# Out of disk space with 25+ GB left in partition

Tags: 12.04, disk-usage

First post here. Somehow I have managed to run out of space on my 12.04 Ubuntu partition even though I am only using 29GB/66.2GB. Please see the below screen shot that shows the gparted gui as well as system monitor filestystm tab.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IPSL.jpg

It seems that my home directory is inside of /dev/loop0. I am not sure how this came to be. The only time I remember doing anything relating to loops was something in an automated script I used to flash a Jetson TK1 with an image.

See output of df -i :

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      3807232 540706  3266526   15% /
udev            1017029    572  1016457    1% /dev
tmpfs           1019366    504  1018862    1% /run
none            1019366      3  1019363    1% /run/lock
none            1019366      8  1019358    1% /run/shm
/dev/sda5      38674300    184 38674116    1% /host
```

See what happens when I try to copy a file that is too large (this is not the actual event that caused me to notice this problem, but it was requested to show such an error)

```
andrew@ubuntu:~/JetsonTK1Files$ cp Tegra_Linux_Sample-Root-Filesystem_R19.3.0_armhf.tbz2 test.tbz2
cp: writing `test.tbz2': No space left on device
cp: failed to extend `test.tbz2': No space left on device
```

How do I fix this such that I can utilize all 66.2GB? Please let me know if I can provide any more information to help is answering this.

Edit: Partition size previously incorrectly stated as 56GB, added output of df -i, added example error

Comment: The partition size is 66.2 GB, not 56 GB. Please append the output of `df -i` at the end of your question.

Comment: Ok. Whats the exact error message you are getting while reading/writing data?

Comment: I have done a simple copy to produce an error because I can no longer re-do what originally caused the problem. I was running a program with the Robot Operating System (ROS) and when the disk became full something very bad happened and it broke ROS.

Comment: Remove unnecessary files from `/dev/loop0` (**"/"**) to make some free space and then try again.

Comment: How I know which files correspond to dev/loop0. Im afraid I dont understand what you mean by ("/")

Comment: In your system the partition /dev/loop0 is mounted as "/". As its showing 86.8 MB only free in "/", so you need to clear that partition. In a nutshell you need enough free space in the root directory ("/") as important system related files are stored in various subdirectories of the root directory in the file system hierarchy. In your system the "/host" is mount on "/dev/sda5" and "/" on "/dev/loop0". Now you need to remove unnecessary files under "/", not "/host". The easy way to understand that will be that he locations will have "/" at the start, not "/host".

Comment: I suppose while that would allow me to save a few files in the nearterm what I am looking for is a way to allocate all (or nearly all) 66.2 GB to ("/") because that is where everything I have resides... Is that a nonsensical desire?

Comment: Just to get to the root of the problem just copy (remove if not needed) files under "/" to somewhere else and don't just dump everything in "/" as you have only 28.1 GB allocated for "/". As you don't have any separate partition your "/home", "/boot", "/var" etc directories are all inside that 28.1 GB. Just do a `ls -l /` to get some idea on your current file system hierarchy.

Comment: Ok, now that I have moved some things, how do I advance to fixing the root problem? (meaning how do I reallocate space better?)

Comment: Check the free space by `df -h` and then try to copy the file you tried earlier to some place in "/host".

Comment: /host has plenty of room and it copies to it normally. I dont mean to be impatient, but what are we trying to test/prove?

Comment: In a nutshell, the problem you are facing is due to low space on "/", so copying data from that partition to someplace else will free up the partition and your system will be usable again.

Comment: @heemayl: you're on the right track, but there is something else going on here.  user3535885: can you upload `/etc/fstab` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link in a comment here?